# How to copy a random string generator (from A - Z, 0 - 9) to clipboard?

Tags: c#

I already attempted my own version here:

```
private void button6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string gen(int length)
    {
        const string valid = 
            "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890";

        StringBuilder res = new StringBuilder();
        Random rnd = new Random();

        while (0 < length)
        {
            res.Append(valid[rnd.Next(valid.Length)]);
            Clipboard.SetText(string);
        }

        return res.ToString();
    }
}
```

which does not work at all, I'm not sure if i need SetText(string) or not, but i get an error in the error list: "invalid expression term 'string'"

Comment: It appears that your `while` condition will remain `true` forever. Should you be decrementing `length` inside the loop? And if so, would it make more sense to use a `for` loop?

Comment: Also, wouldn't it make more sense to set the `Clipboard` text *after* the loop completes (i.e. just before the `return` statement, do `Clipboard.SetText(res.ToString());`)? Setting it over and over in a hard loop like that seems unproductive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not setting your generated random string (which is `res`).

change

```
 Clipboard.SetText(string);
```

to

```
 Clipboard.SetText(res.ToString());
```

Comment: beat me by 7seconds

Comment: this happens a lot. ;)

Comment: i don't understand why i get minus votes lol, where's the lack of information?